# Testing an OAuth Secured API with Spring MVC - Test with no token does not fail as expected

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

When i run just the unit test alone for no token provided, the test fails as expected:

```
  @Test
  public void Given_NoTokenProvided_When_getRequest_Then_ReturnsUnauthorized() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get("/helloworld/test")).andExpect(status().isBadRequest());
  }
```

Mockmvc is initialised like so:

```
  private MockMvc mockMvc;
  @Autowired private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

      @Before
      public void before() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
      }
```

I created another passing test within the same Junit class where the token is provided.

Both passes if run individually. However, if i run the Junit class-level test, only the passing test clears. The No-Token test returns a 200 OK response instead of failing:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status 
Expected :400
Actual   :200
```

The unit tests are ordered such that the failing No-Token test runs first. But this still results in the No-Token test returning a 200 OK response instead of 400.

Comment: Could you add the code to show how you are configuring `mockMvc`?

Comment: I've added in what you asked for

Comment: Try adding `.apply(springSecurity()) ` to configure the `MockMvcBuilder` for use with Spring Security, as described in this section of the documentation. https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html5/#test-mockmvc-setup